# Not a uniquely defined Name?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I keep getting the error

"LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR" was not a uniquely defined name.  The definition
                        to be used could not be determined from the context.

And similar on all of my counters. I have no idea where I'm going wrong here, how is it not a uniquely defined name when it is clearly in the WORKING-STORAGE SECTION? Do I put it somewhere else so that it's a uniquely defined name? Below I have showed where I defined my counters, and where the counters are used.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. LAB3.
   AUTHOR.  

  ******************************************************************
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
  *  defines the external files - an input file and output file
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.


       SELECT SALES-FILE ASSIGN TO DATAIN
          FILE STATUS IS EF-STATUS.

       SELECT REPORT-FILE ASSIGN TO DATAOUT
          FILE STATUS IS PF-STATUS.
   DATA DIVISION.
  * has two sections - the file section that describes the files
  * and the working storage section - where output lines and
  * processing variables are defined

   FILE SECTION.

   FD SALES-FILE.
   01 SALES-RECORD.
       05 EMPLOYEE-NAME-IN PIC X(24).
       05 SALES-IN           PIC 99999.
       05 FILLER             PIC X(51).
   FD REPORT-FILE.
   01 REPORT-RECORD                PIC X(80).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01 FLAGS-AND-ACCUMLATORS.
       05 LOW-COMMISSION-CTR   PIC 99999 VALUE ZERO.
       05 LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR PIC 99999 VALUE ZERO.
       05 HIGHMID-COMMISSION-CTR PIC 99999 VALUE ZERO.
       05 HIGH-COMMISSION-CTR   PIC 99999 VALUE ZERO.
       05 TOTAL-SALES PIC $$$,$$9.99 VALUE ZERO.
       05 TOTAL-COMMISSION PIC $$$,$$9.99 VALUE ZERO.
       05   END-OF-FILE            PIC XXX VALUE "NO".
       05   EF-STATUS              PIC 99  VALUE 0.
       05   PF-STATUS              PIC 99  VALUE 0.
       05   COMMISSION             PIC 99999V99.

   01 REPORT-BLANK-LINE.
       05                          PIC X(80).

   01  HEADING-LINE-1.
       05                          PIC X(30) VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(19) VALUE
            "COMPANY OF AARON".



   01  HEADING-LINE-2.
        05                          PIC X(30) VALUE SPACES.
        05                          PIC X(19) VALUE
              "KEARNEY, MISSOURI".
   01  HEADING-LINE-3.
        05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
        05                      PIC X(48) VALUE
              "Number of employees with up to 10,000 in sales: ".
        05 LOW-COMMISSION-CTR PIC 99999.
   01  HEADING-LINE-4.
        05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
        05                      PIC X(52) VALUE
              "Number of employees from 10,001 to 20,000 in sales: ".
        05 LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR PIC 99999.
   01 HEADING-LINE-5.
        05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
        05                      PIC X(52) VALUE
           "Number of employees from 20,001 to 30,000 in sales: ".
        05 HIGHMID-COMMISSION-CTR PIC 99999.
   01 HEADING-LINE-6.
        05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
        05                      PIC X(42) VALUE
           "Number of employees over 30,000 in sales: ".
        05 HIGH-COMMISSION-CTR PIC 99999.
   01 HEADING-LINE-7.
        05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
        05                      PIC X(13) VALUE
            "Total Sales: ".
        05 TOTAL-SALES PIC $$$,$$9.99.
   01 HEADING-LINE-8.
        05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
        05                      PIC X(18) VALUE
             "TOTAL COMMISSION: ".
        05 TOTAL-COMMISSION PIC $$$,$$9.99.

   01  COLUMN-HEADING-1.
        05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
        05                      PIC X(24) VALUE "SALESPERSON".
        05                      PIC X(15) VALUE "SALES".
        05                      PIC X(10) VALUE "COMMISSION".
   01  COLUMN-HEADING-2.
        05                      PIC X(14) VALUE "SUMMARY REPORT".


   01  DETAIL-LINE.
        05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
        05 EMPLOYEE-NAME-OUT    PIC X(24).
        05 SALES-OUT            PIC $$$,$$9.
        05                      PIC X(05) VALUE SPACES.
        05 COMMISSION-OUT       PIC $$$,$$9.99.


   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   1000-MAIN-CONTROL.
       PERFORM 2000-INITIALIZE.
       PERFORM UNTIL END-OF-FILE = "YES"
         READ SALES-FILE
           AT END
             MOVE "YES" TO END-OF-FILE
           NOT AT END
             PERFORM 3000-PROCESS
       END-PERFORM
       PERFORM 4000-PROCESS.
       STOP RUN.

   2000-INITIALIZE.
          OPEN INPUT SALES-FILE
               OUTPUT REPORT-FILE.

       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-1.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-2.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM REPORT-BLANK-LINE.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM COLUMN-HEADING-1.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM REPORT-BLANK-LINE.

    3000-PROCESS.

       IF SALES-IN < 10001
         MULTIPLY SALES-IN BY .04 GIVING COMMISSION
          ADD 1 TO LOW-COMMISSION-CTR
          ADD COMMISSION TO TOTAL-COMMISSION
       END-IF.


       IF SALES-IN > 10000 AND < 20001
         MULTIPLY SALES-IN BY .055 GIVING COMMISSION
          ADD 1 TO LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR
          ADD COMMISSION TO TOTAL-COMMISSION
       END-IF.

       IF SALES-IN > 20000 AND < 30000
         MULTIPLY SALES-IN BY .065 GIVING COMMISSION
          ADD 1 TO HIGHMID-COMMISSION-CTR
          ADD COMMISSION TO TOTAL-COMMISSION
          END-IF.

       IF SALES-IN > 30000
         MULTIPLY SALES-IN BY .075 GIVING COMMISSION
          ADD 1 TO HIGH-COMMISSION-CTR
          ADD COMMISSION TO TOTAL-COMMISSION
          END-IF.

       MOVE EMPLOYEE-NAME-IN       TO EMPLOYEE-NAME-OUT.
       MOVE SALES-IN               TO SALES-OUT.
       MOVE COMMISSION             TO COMMISSION-OUT.

       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM DETAIL-LINE.

   4000-PROCESS.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM REPORT-BLANK-LINE.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM COLUMN-HEADING-2.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-3.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-4.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-5.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-6.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-7.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-8.
   4000-TERMINATE.
       CLOSE SALES-FILE, REPORT-FILE.
```

Comment: I'd trust the compiler and look for another definition somewhere. You've only posted part of your code here, so it's not likely we'll be able to help. This is not a request for you to post more!

Comment: but what do you mean by that?

Comment: You are using IBM's Enterprise COBOL, not OpenCOBOL, so I've changed your tags.

Comment: A simple search in your text editor and you would have found the second declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thje variable LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR is defined twice.

- once in FLAGS-AND-ACCUMLATORS

```
     01 FLAGS-AND-ACCUMLATORS.
        05 LOW-COMMISSION-CTR   PIC 99999 VALUE ZERO.
        05 LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR PIC 99999 VALUE ZERO.
```

- once in HEADING-LINE-4

```
     01  HEADING-LINE-4.
         05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
         05                      PIC X(52) VALUE
               "Number of employees from 10,001 to 20,000 in sales: ".
         05 LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR PIC 99999.
```

So either

- rename one of the  LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR to some thing else

```
     01  HEADING-LINE-4.
         05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
         05                      PIC X(52) VALUE
               "Number of employees from 10,001 to 20,000 in sales: ".
         05 HEADER-LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR PIC 99999.
```

- fully qualify the field.

```
     Add 1 
      to    LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR 
         of FLAGS-AND-ACCUMLATORS
```

Same applies to other FLAGS-AND-ACCUMLATORS fields

Comment: I put my entire code up there, I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong because I dont think I have 2 variables with that name. I am having the same problem on two other programs

Comment: @user38254  LOWMID-COMMISSION-CTR is defined twice, once in flags and accumulators and once in Heading-4

Comment: @user38254 you have five fields under your FLAGS-AND-ACCUMLATORS whose names are repeated in HEADING-LINE-3 through HEADING-LINE-7.

Comment: Oh.. I thought I could just simply put the variable there to print it. Whoops.

Comment: I am now getting this error? `137  IGYPA3074-S   "TOTAL-COMMISSION (NUMERIC-EDITED)" was not numeric, but was a sender in an arithmetic expression.  The
                      statement was discarded.
 
                      Same message on line:    144    150    156
 
   159  IGYPA3074-S   "TOTAL-SALES (NUMERIC-EDITED)" was not numeric, but was a sender in an arithmetic expression.  The statement
                      was discarded.   `

Comment: @user38254 You usually have numeric fields for accumulating values, and numeric-edited fields for printing values. I'd suggest giving different names in your various lines for printing and MOVE for each before the report lines are written.